# Join a long data frame to a tidy data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, join, merge

I have two dataframes like below:

```
df1 <- data.frame(Construction = c("Frame","Frame","Masonry","Fire Resistive","Masonry"),
                 Industry = c("Apartments","Restaurant","Condos","Condos","Condos"),
                 Size = c("[0-3)","[6-9)","[3-6)","[3-6)","9+"))
```

```
df2 <- data.frame(Category = c("Construction","Construction","Construction",
                               "Industry","Industry","Industry",
                               "Size","Size","Size","Size"),
                      Type = c("Frame","Masonry","Fire Resistive",
                               "Apartments","Restaurant","Condos",
                                "[0-3)","[3-6)","[6-9)","9+"),
                      Score1 = rnorm(10),
                      Score2 = rnorm(10),
                      Score3 = rnorm(10))
```

I want to *join* `df2` to `df1` so that `Construction`, `Industry`, and `Size` each have their respective `Score`.

I can do it manually by making a `key` equal to `Category` concatenated with `Type` and then doing a *left-join* for each column, but I want a way to automate it so I can add/remove variables easily.

Here's the format I want it to look like: *(note: `Score` numbers don't match.)*

```
df3 <-  data.frame(Construction = c("Frame","Frame","Masonry","Fire Resistive","Masonry"),
                   Construction_Score1 = rnorm(5),
                   Construction_Score2 = rnorm(5),
                   Construction_Score3 = rnorm(5),
                   Industry = c("Apartments","Restaurant","Condos","Condos","Condos"),
                   Industry_Score1 = rnorm(5),
                   Industry_Score2 = rnorm(5),
                   Industry_Score3 = rnorm(5),
                   Size = c("[0-3)","[6-9)","[3-6)","[3-6)","9+"),
                   Size_Score1 = rnorm(5),
                   Size_Score2 = rnorm(5),
                   Size_Score3 = rnorm(5))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea here is joining `df1` and `df2` on `c("Construction","Industry","Size")` and `Type` and then construct a *long* dataframe consist of those merged dataframe which we later convert to wide to get it in the format you desired.

```
mylist <- lapply(names(df1), function(col){
                              merge(x = df1, y = df2, 
                                    by.x = col, by.y = "Type", 
                                    all.x = TRUE)})

mydf <- do.call(rbind, mylist)

df3 <- reshape(mydf, idvar = c("Construction","Industry","Size"), 
                     timevar = "Category", 
                     direction = "wide")
```

<sub>One thing to note is that you have `Score` as the value of your *`Category`* column in `df2` which I think should be `Size` instead to match what you have in `df3` and also what has been hinted in `df1`.</sub>

---

---

**Update:** Answering OP's [follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56027546/join-a-long-data-frame-to-a-tidy-data-frame/56028442?noredirect=1#comment98701310_56028442);

- *What if there are other columns that are in `df1`, but not `df2`?*

Let's make `df11` which has another column and apply the same approach on that:

```
df11 <- cbind(df1, a=1:5)

mydf <- do.call(rbind,
                      lapply(names(df11[1:3]), function(col){
                                               merge(x = df11, y = df2, 
                                                     by.x = col, by.y = "Type", 
                                                     all.x = TRUE)}))

df33 <- reshape(mydf, idvar = names(df11), 
               timevar = "Category", 
               direction = "wide")
```

So, you just need to specify in `lapply` which columns of `df11` you are using to `merge` with `df2` and in the `reshape` you include all the columns from `df11` whether they match with `df2` or not.

---

---

Another possibility using `tidyverse` package (Thanks to @akrun for reminding me about `map_df`):

```
map_df(names(df11)[1:3], ~ left_join(df11, df2, by = set_names("Type", .x))) %>% 
gather(mvar, mval, Score1:Score3) %>% 
unite(var, mvar, Category) %>% 
spread(var, mval)
```

Comment: Thanks! What if there are other columns that are in df1, but not df2?

Comment: @user3304359 instead of defining which columns of `df11` you are using in `merge` you can find the `intersect(names(df11), names(df2))`.